# SQL data types - what are you supposed to do with years outside the allowed 1901 to 2155 range?

Tags: mysql, sql

> YEAR  A year in four-digit format. Values allowed in four-digit format: 1901 to 2155

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

> YEAR accepts input values in a variety of formats: [...]
> As 4-digit numbers in the range 1901 to 2155.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/year.html

> In four-digit format, the allowable values are 1901 to 2155, and 0000.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/year-data-type/

> YEAR(MySQL) data type can store only the year in 2 digits or 4 digit format. It can store 4 digit format the year between 1901 to 2155 and in 2-digit format from 70 to 69, representing 1970 to 2069.

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/sql-date-functions-examples/

I don't get that at all; what are you supposed do do with year data outside that date range, like say, 1066? https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/learn/histories/1066-and-the-norman-conquest/

Ninja edit: I suppose you must have to store the entire column in question as an `int`, but if so, why?? That seems crazy to me...

Comment: `YEAR` is a [rather limited] data type in MySQL that can come in handy on special cases where you will be storing years between 1901 and 2155. That's it. If you are modeling other ranges, then you'll be better using `INT` or `SMALLINT`.

Comment: OK, thanks, but is there some reason why they restricted the range? I just can't fathom why that would be?

Comment: You'll notice it stores exactly 256 cases: 1901-2155 + 0000. It seems like the designers tried to save storage and used a single byte for it. RAM and disk were expensive back in the day, so this may have been a good solution. Nowadays -- that you have GBs of RAM and TBs of disk -- it's not a good one anymore.

Comment: And 0000 isn't even a valid year. The first year is 1...

Comment: In an alternate reality, we'd be asking why MySQL uses four bytes for the YEAR type, when virtually all users only need year values between 1901 and 2155, and the value could be stored in one byte.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, the romans didn't have a concept for zero back in the day: all started at 1. it took the western world 1100 years to finally accept it. There's a documentary about it somewhere...

Comment: @TheImpaler - Ahhhhh, suddenly it all makes sense. I was wondering 'why 2155???' but that would explain it. Thanks!!